# Can Json.NET deserialize to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>?

Tags: json.net

Can Json.NET deserialize to this?

```
public class C
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public C(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> values)
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you share your json data.

Comment: @Amit, if you think it's relevant, `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`.

Comment: @Pac0, I don't want a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Just deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, string>` and call `ToList()`  on it.

```
var myJson = @"{""key1"": ""value1"", ""key2"": ""value2""}";

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myEnumerable;

myEnumerable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(myJson).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't want to deserialize `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}` into something. I want to deserialize something into an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Comment: you cannot deserialize to the interface (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>), you need a concrete type to deserialize. Here, in this case, you can use Dictionary<string, string> and directly assign it to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>.